# Free version of Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to learn Dynamics CRM 2011. But found it quite expensive for a self learner. Is there any student version or Limited edition available which I can use to learn. 30 Trial is not enough for be because I am only planning to play around during free time.

Thanks

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have any option apart from trial version. Or try CRM 2011 - Online which is around £40 per month. Try to use Online trial version and buy if you find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the trial version is totally deactivated after 60 days, however I suggest to continue to use the trial.

It's also helpful to activate two trials at the same time, in this way you can practice with the importing/exporting solution process.